# Get value of an Attribute-decorated property

Tags: c#, validation, maxlength

i want to make some validations in a class, so i thought I could use attributes.
Like this:

```
public class someClass
{
    [Lenght(200)]
    public string someStr { get; set; }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class Lenght  : Attribute
{
    public Lenght(int Lenght)
    {
         //some code   
    }
}
```

But I know that I can't do it, because this is not how attributes work. And, if there is a way, it would use some kind of heavy reflection and kludges that I want to avoid.

The validation I want to do is like this:

```
public class someClass
{

    public string someStr
    {
        get
        {
            return _someStr;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > 200)
            {
                throw new Exception("Max Length is 200!");
            }
            else _someStr = value;
        }
    }
    private string _someStr { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to do it faster, without all this code. I want as fast as using an Attribute.

There is a way i could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would not do stuff like this with an attribute, but it is possible, although not recommendable. Use at your own risk :) (you will let loose hell if the property is not decorated with the `LengthAttribute` :) )

```
    public interface AttributeValidator
    {
        void CheckOk(object value);
    }

    public class LenghtAttribute : Attribute, AttributeValidator
    {
        public int MaxLength { get; private set; }
        public LenghtAttribute(int lenght)
        {
            this.MaxLength = lenght;
        }

        public void CheckOk(object value)
        {
            var str = value as string;
            if (str != value)
                throw new Exception("Not a string!");

            if (str != null && str.Length > MaxLength)
                throw new Exception("To long!");
        }
    }

    public class DoesNotContain : Attribute, AttributeValidator
    {
        public string Chars { get; private set; }
        public DoesNotContain(string chars)
        {
            this.Chars = chars;
        }

        public void CheckOk(object value)
        {
            var str = value as string;
            if (str != value)
                throw new Exception("Not a string!");

            if (str != null && Chars.Any(c => str.Contains(c)))
                throw new Exception("Contains forbidden character!");
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private string _someString;

        [Lenght(200)]
        [DoesNotContain("$#2")]
        public string SomeString
        {
            get { return _someString; }
            set
            {
                Utils.Validate("SomeString", this, value);
                _someString = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Utils
    {
        public static void Validate(string property, object instance, string value)
        {
            var validators = instance.GetType().GetProperty(property)
                .GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AttributeValidator>();

            foreach (var validator in validators)
                validator.CheckOk(value);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** I've extended the example. Still a horrible solution, but it works.

Comment: It has been 2 years since I posted this question, and today I was reviewing my questions here in SO.

I have learnt some C# since then, I wouldn't ask this question now, neither I would use attributes to validate it. 

I accepted your answer because you put some effort into it, I would just like to point that your code in SomeClass does almost the same thing as I had posted in my question, but whatever.

Also, after having some experience with in-property validations, I never want to do this again, I never expect to throw an exception inside a property. I changed my mind completely since then.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method which takes the field as a `ref` parameter:

```
public static void SetWithMaxLength(ref string field, string value, int maxLength)
{
    if(value.Length > maxLength) throw new Exception("Max length is " + maxLength);
    field = value;
}
```

then you could write your setter as:

```
set
{
    SetWithMaxLength(ref this._someStr, value, 200);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I could study more about ref and out parameters... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an attribute is to declare metadata about an assembly, type, member, parameter, etc. to other components, tools, the compiler, etc. Sure, you could do what you are asking, but that would involve reflecting over itself which is a long way to go to just assert the value as you do in your second example.

What you should consider instead is a validation framework that has all this stuff built in for you, and allows you to validate separately and externally.

There are a number of validation frameworks to choose from. Two popular ones off the top of my head are [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and Enterprise Library's [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

On the other hand, perhaps you are just looking for a good [Guard](http://conditions.codeplex.com/) class or [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/). These serve a different purpose than validation (see [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)). You could conceivably combine attributes (I'd recommend reusing [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)) with some aspect-oriented programming to have the guard stuff done for you declaratively (see [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)). That, however, would probably just be showing off :).

Comment: This FluentValidation Framework seems interesting, but i dont like the idea of using a framework for this basic validation...but it seems very interesting...